# Induced Isomorphism on 2nd Homology Group

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I have two related questions:

> 1) Is there a continuous map from the 2-sphere to the torus inducing
>   an isomorphism on the 2nd (integral) homology groups?
>
> 2) Is there a continuous map from the torus to the 2-sphere inducing
>   an isomorphism on the 2nd (integral) homology groups?

---

My attempt: I know that $H_2(T)=\mathbb{Z}$, and $H_2(S^2)=\mathbb{Z}$.

And I saw this theorem in Hatcher: If two maps $f,g:(X,A)\to (Y,B)$ are homotopic through maps of pairs $(X,A)\to (Y,B)$, then $f_*=g_*:H_n(X,A)\to H_n(Y,B)$.

Not sure if it is related to this question.

---

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hint: What is $\pi_2(T)$?

Comment: I googled and found it is trivial group. I haven't learnt homotopy group though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. $S^2 \to T^2$ be a continuous map. As $S^2$ is simply connected, you can lift this map to the universal cover of $T^2$. But any map $S^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ is nullhomotopic by straightline homotopy. Now pushdown this homotopy to get a nullhomotopy of $S^2 \to T^2$. So every map from sphere to torus induces the zero map on the 2nd homology group.
2. Yes, consider the map $T^2 \to S^2$ given by quotienting the $1$-skeleton (the wedge of two circles) of $T^2$. Consider the long exact sequence for $(T^2, S^1 \vee S^1)$ where $S^1 \vee S^1$ is the wedge of circles. Consider the following piece : $$H_2(S^1 \vee S^1) \to H_2(T^2) \to H_2(S^2) \to H_1(S^1 \vee S^1) \to H_1(T^2) \to \cdots$$ As $H_2(S^2 \vee S^1) = 0$, the map $H_2(T^2) \to H_2(S^2)$ induced from the quotient map is an injection. Since $S^1 \vee S^1 \hookrightarrow T^2$ induces an isomorphism on $H_1$, the next map is an isomorphism, so $H_2(T^2) \to H_2(S^2)$ is in fact an isomorphism.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just to ask which textbook do you recommend for learning Homology?

Comment: @yoyostein I learnt homology theory from Hatcher's algebraic topology book. It's on chapter 2, but you really don't need anything from chapter 0 or 1. You may want to have a look, it's available online : http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html.

Comment: Why does S1∨S1↪T2 induce an isomorphism on homology?How can we conclude $H_2(T^2) \to H_2(S^2)$ is surjective?

Comment: @BalarkaSen regarding your 2nd map, why does this isomorphism imply that the map q isn't nullhomotopic? (this is the 2nd half of the question in Hatcher)